# Observable Chain Strategy to cycle through list items

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, declarative

Im struggling coming up with a declarative strategy cycle through a dynamic list of items.  My requirements are

1. Each item should be displayed for a minimum of a prescribed time(say 1 second) as long as its still valid
2. Newly arriving messages should always be inserted directly after the currently displayed message
3. If a message is invalidated while it is currently displayed it should immediately move to the next message

I have created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpu11b?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that although ugly models the behavior I desire with the small exception that in an ideal world if there is only 1 message in the list that has been displayed for 1 second already when the second message is inserted it is displayed immediately whereas right now this is more or less polled at 1 second.  My strategy was to use a linked list to maintain the insertion order an `interval` observable to control timing

Im looking for insight on how to make this more elegant, hopefully correct the timing issue mentioned above.  I feel its become rather imperative rather than declarative

Comment: I'm not too sure about what you're trying to achieve but I've tried this solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cayagw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts If it's not doing what you want let me know more about what you expect :) If it's what you want I'm happy to write a proper solution and explain how this works

Comment: Thanks @maxime1992  I dont think this holds to requirement #2.  It also only cycles through once where it should repeat indefinitely.  I also dont see a way to remove messages

Comment: Happy to help but I think I just don't understand what you want. Maybe an example explaining second after second what you expect would help

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're on the right way. You can build it with help of Promises, so it can be chained.

You can apply also the events or signals approach, but isn't good idea rather than chained Promise usage.

I believe that you can encapsulate it with some kind of chained `Actions` which request the `new Action(invoke, duration)` and that `Actions` will be invoking them by `next()` method and just awaits previous `Action` success executing.